# Changes made in js file or views file or css file doesn't gets reflected for the user

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic, service-worker, html5-appcache

I have developed a single page web application with multiple views on it. For rendering these views `ng-if` has been used.

Each view has a separate controller. Many click functionality has been handled using Jquery. For backend, java has been used. The whole application has been developed in `spring MVC` and deployed on `WebLogic`.

The **problem is** whenever I make any changes to the views or the js file it won't get reflected after deploying the new WAR file without clearing cache and doing a hard refresh`(ctrl+F5/R)`.

I got an answer to this question few minutes ago which was related to ServiceWorker and appCache but it no more in the answer list.
Do anyone have any idea about this?

I need a permanent solution for this as I have more than `5000` users and I can't ask everyone to do this after each deployment.

I have **tried** to provide a version when I include it in an `index.jsp` like `(filename.js?version=2.1)`. But this doesn't seem working for me. I haven't tested this on `chrome` or any other browser as only `IE10`, `edge` is available for me as well as the users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to provide versioning for css, js, jsp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818898/how-to-provide-versioning-for-css-js-jsp-files)

Comment: See "Invalidating and updating cached responses" https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching. Changing the file name is suggested there. Appending a random query string has worked for me in the past although you say this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a query at the end of JS file imported only work on a client side language.
If you are using a JSP file you can add this at the beginning of your file it will disable caching

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
%>
```

For IE you need to add these HTML tags :

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

You can specify an expiration date for the file in `response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);`
See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13158_01/alui/wci/docs103/devguide/tsk_pagelets_settingcaching_httpexpires.html) for more information

Comment: as you suggested it will disable caching but it will slow down the application as each time it will download the included files. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but in setDateHeader you can specify a date of expiration. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13158_01/alui/wci/docs103/devguide/tsk_pagelets_settingcaching_httpexpires.html for more information